# Set up google analytics oauth for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to set up an app that allows users to authenticate into their google analytics account once and store some key to later pull data from their accounts; even if only one account to start. I looked at the legato gem and google analytics gem but it seems there are restrictions to only using it for your own analytics account or it times out your connection after 30 min. Is there any way to set up persistent login with an auth key so I can pull data continuously for my clients?

Comment: You can only access the GA accounts for which the supplied email has access to. Honestly speaking, Google is about to roll out 2FA compulsion, so this might be a pain for u

Comment: Thanks, so you can confirm there is no way to store auth keys for permitting accounts outside of my own to pull analytics data?

Comment: No mate you dont, I can confirm that :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm hearing back from someone at google. I'll post here if I find any work arounds